# How do i create and deploy a directed graph (with large data size) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, algorithm, graph

The algorithm should be relatively faster, I am familiar to closure table algorithm which is restricted only to hierarchical data.

Is there any way to implement it in mysql or i have to switch to any other database (which should be open source).

For instance consider the following graph.

```
1, 2
1, 3
1, 5
2, 4
3, 4
5, 8
2, 8
4, 6
4, 7
```

I need algorithm and Queries to pull out whole the graph optimally

Comment: Why not put the graph representation into file and throw that into SQL db? or you can have 2 columns (from, to)  in the table and each edge is a row. when you want to look for edges going to/from a vertex you simply use filter.

Comment: Do you want that using only mysql commands or using a programming language that have integration with mysql (ex java with jdbc) ?